# xml split because of junk python

Tags: python

I am getting an xml string from namedpipe of buffer size (4096) : 
here is the xml string

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
 <response id="rp001">
 <command opcode="-ac">
    <mode value="tester" />
    <key value="AKIAJVW3VWOTZL5UAAYQ" />
    <passkey value="QpPLmpdl89zAza+nv5fmCMta5ZsPvGkbFvJ6xWZH" />
    <name value="test" />                    
   </command>
 </response>
 ˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛˛
```

i am getting this unreadable characters after response. what i am think is to chop the characters after `</response>` and strore the value in another variable. how do i do this chop or spilt.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml = xml.split('</response>', 1)[0] + '</response>'
```

Comment: so my xmlstring will contain only characters till `</response>` right ?